# WinForm C# list box ,click button ,txt box. sum of items

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I'm trying to create a program that gives the user a list box full of items and their respective prices. When the user selects an item and clicks the add to order button it will add the item to a order summary listbox and also add the price of that item to a subtotal textbox. I have it almost fully functional but my problem is that I can't get the subtotal to add up. What I mean is when I add one item to the summary list box it displays the price in the subtotal textbox but when I add a second item to the summary list box it doesn't add to the previous price in the subtotal text box instead it just replaces the price of the first item with the price of the second item. How can I get them to add up and display them in the subtotal text box?

Here's how my code looks now under a btn click event handler:

double subTotal = 0.00;

```
if (lstBoxItemSelection.Text =="Item 1 = 1.00")
    { 
         LstBoxSummary.Items.Add("Item 1 = 1.00")
         subTotal += 1.00;
     }

if (lstBoxItemSelection.Text =="Item 2 = 2.00"  )
     { 
         LstBoxSummary.Items.Add("Item 2 = 2.00")
         subTotal += 2.00;
     }

this.txtBoxSubTotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: My guess is that your subTotal variable is declared in the scope of the method.. this means that each time you add something to your subtotal it adds something to zero. You can solve this by moving your declaration outside of the method or set the subtotal equal to the double value of your subtotal textbox value (parse the string-value) in the beginning of your method ..

Answer (score 0):

I think your `subTotal` variable is a local variable. That mean the value will be reset each time you click on the button.
Try to put it out of the method :

```
private double subTotal = 0.0;
private void btn_click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   if (lstBoxItemSelection.Text =="Item 1 = 1.00")
   { 
        LstBoxSummary.Items.Add("Item 1 = 1.00")
        subTotal += 1.00;
   }

   if (lstBoxItemSelection.Text =="Item 2 = 2.00"  )
   { 
        LstBoxSummary.Items.Add("Item 2 = 2.00")
        subTotal += 2.00;
   }

   this.txtBoxSubTotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response it works great I knew it would be something super simple that I just overlooked

Comment: Don't forget to put the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Your subTotal does only exist in the event handler for that single event.
The next time you have a new subTotal.

Move subTotal out of the eventhandler or parse your field and add it to subtotal

```
this.txtBoxSubTotal.Text = (float.Parse(this.txtBoxSubTotal.Text,
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
                            + subTotal).ToString();
```